# Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can anyone help me with this VB Code:

```
 <%If (Eval("NewPrice")) =0 Then%>
                        <% Session("OrigenalPrice") = True%>
                        <asp:Label ID="Pricelabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' />
                        <%Else%>
                        <% Session("OrigenalPrice") = False%>
                        <asp:Label ID="NewPricelabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NewPrice") %>' />
                        <asp:Label ID="OldPricelabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' />
                        <%End If%>
```

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Why don't you put this in code-behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571545/databinding-methods-such-as-eval-xpath-and-bind-can-only-be-used-in-the) you'll find the answer (you should move the `<%If (Eval("NewPrice")) =0 Then%>` part to code behind).