# Error while data binding to grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have following code in gridview:

```
 <% If Eval("LabelType").ToString() = "Singleline" Then%>  <asp:TextBox ID="txtSingleLine" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox> <% End If%>
 <% If Eval("LabelType").ToString() = "Multiline" Then%>  <asp:TextBox ID="txtMultiline" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox> <% End If%>                                            
  <% If Eval("LabelType").ToString() = "Image" Then%>  <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /> <% End If%>
```

I am getting following error:

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571545/databinding-methods-such-as-eval-xpath-and-bind-can-only-be-used-in-the) question i came to know that # should be added, but when i added as:

It was not accepting this (showing blue line below whole statement).

Please tell me where i am making mistake.

Please help me.

I am using vb.net but answer in c# is also helpful.

Comment: @KevinKunderman i already mentioned this in my question, that i haqve refered that question

Comment: Can you add markup for whole grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the visibility on each control based on the value of LabelType like so:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSingleLine" runat="server" Visible="<%# Eval("LabelType").ToString() == "Singleline" %>"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMultiline" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine"  Visible="<%# Eval("LabelType").ToString() == "Multiline" %>" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  Visible="<%# Eval("LabelType").ToString() == "Image" %>" />
```

Comment: Thanx, this was easiest way :)

Comment: but, this always shows me single line textbox , no matter whatever is the text. eg. if its multiline, it shows me single line+multiline, if its image , it shows me single line +image uploader

Comment: Strange, post the markup for the gridview, as well as the code that populates it.

Comment: yeah, its done, it was my mistake. Thank you, helpful answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Like the error says you cannot have an `Eval` outside of data bound control, so I would recommend that you dynamically insert the controls into a `PlaceHolder` control, like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Code-behind:

```
If LabelType = "Singleline" Then
    ' Create textbox and add to placeholder
    Dim textbox = New TextBox()
    textbox.ID = "txtSingleLine"
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox)
Else If LabelType = "Multiline" Then
    ' Create textbox with multi-line text mode and add to placeholder
    Dim multilinetextbox = New TextBox()
    multilinetextbox.ID = "txtMultiline"
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(multilinetextbox)
Else If LabelType = "Image" Then
    ' Create file upload and add to placeholder
    Dim fileupload = New FileUpload()
    fileupload.ID = "FileUpload1"
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(fileupload)
End If
```

Note: `LabelType` in the code above is the string representation of what you were doing in `Eval("LabelType").ToString()`.