# Error: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control in repeater control

Tags: asp.net, eval, repeater

I am getting the following error

```
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control
```

but I am trying to write my code in ASP.NET REPEATER Control as

```
<%if (Eval("IsBreakPoint") == "1")
    { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Category") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="27">
            </td>
       </tr>
    <%} %>
```

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571545/databinding-methods-such-as-eval-xpath-and-bind-can-only-be-used-in-the)

Answer (score 15):

The `<% if %>` statement doesn't support databinding.

For conditional display, I always try to databind to the `Visible` property of a single server control.

In a case like yours involving a block of markup (rather than a single server control), I'd wrap that block in an `<asp:PlaceHolder>` control as follows:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="CategoryPlaceHolder" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("IsBreakPoint") == "1") %>'>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Category") %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="27">
        </td>
   </tr>

</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Or if you aren't really using that label server-side:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="CategoryPlaceHolder" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("IsBreakPoint") == "1") %>'>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%# Eval("Category") %>
        </td>
        <td colspan="27">
        </td>
   </tr>

</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Or more readable still: if you can define the [ItemType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.itemtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property for the Repeater, then you will get strong typing and Intellisense at design-time (this would be my recommended approach):

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="CategoryPlaceHolder" runat="server" Visible='<%# Item.IsBreakPoint == "1") %>'>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%# Item.Category %>
        </td>
        <td colspan="27">
        </td>
   </tr>

</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Take care to use single quotes around the `Visible` value when that expression contains double quotes. (Ahh, as you have already done with the `Label.Text` property.)

Answer (score 2):

Got an answer... and it worked...

```
   <%#(Eval("IsBreakPoint")) == "1" ? Eval("Category", "<tr bgcolor:#D4FFC4><td colspan='28'><b>{0}</b></td></tr>") : ""%>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to change that to `<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"field")%>`

Comment: i love this solution, simple and verry usable

Answer (score 0):

> We Can not Use Conditional Method Like if .. Else switch ... Case in
>   DataList ...

```
<%if (Eval("IsBreakPoint") == "1")
```

use

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Category") %>' visible="<# Eval("IsBreakPoint")==1 "></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="27">
        </td>
   </tr>
```