# How to use IF ELSE using EVAL condition in aspx c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I am trying to use `if else` conditions in aspx page using `Eval` conditions. But its showing error red line in `else` condition and in `)` in `if` condition.

Code

```
<div class="price_mth text-center">
<% if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("PromoPrice", "{0:,00}").ToString()) %>) { %>
<asp:panel id="pricePanel" runat="server" >
<h2><i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i> <%# Eval("Price", "{0:,00}") %><sup>.00/mo</sup></h2>
</asp:panel>
 <% } %>

<% else { %>                                              
<asp:panel id="promopanel" runat="server">
<div class="style-1">
 <h2> <del><i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="amount"><%# Eval("Price", "{0:,00}") %></span> </del><sup>.00/mo</sup></h2>
 <h2><ins><i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="amount"><%# Eval("PromoPrice", "{0:,00}") %></span></ins><sup>.00/mo</sup></h2>
</div>
 </asp:panel>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I can't test your code but I know you should  use ForExample:`1 + 2 =<%= (1+2).ToString() %>` then this code maybe work.`<% if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("PromoPrice", "{0:,00}").ToString())) { %>` or `<% if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(<%# Eval("PromoPrice", "{0:,00}").ToString()) %>) { %>`

Comment: Hi @SoheilaTarighi thanks for response, i try but now its showing this error message `Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.`

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571545/databinding-methods-such-as-eval-xpath-and-bind-can-only-be-used-in-the

Comment: Thanks my issue resolved.... i have try visible property

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method as shown below:

```
<asp:Panel ID="p1" Visible='<%# BLL.Logic.ShowPanel(Eval("PromoPrice", "{0:,00}")) %>' runat="server">   
</asp:Panel>
```