# Pass session to if condition in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep1" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
                                               
       <%if ((Eval("Member_ID").ToString()) == Session["StuID"].ToString()) {%>
...some code
```

but when I run the code this error message appears:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Databinding methods such as Eval(),
> XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound
> control.' This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]
> ASP.adminsection_empchat_aspx.__Render__control4(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter,
> System.Web.UI.Control) in EmpChat.aspx
> [External Code]

Comment: Any question here on SO is very important. Why should yours be more important than the others? ;o)

Comment: Does [Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571545/databinding-methods-such-as-eval-xpath-and-bind-can-only-be-used-in-the) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571545/databinding-methods-such-as-eval-xpath-and-bind-can-only-be-used-in-the)